# Center textview in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to center my textview in the linearlayout. I don't understand why this isn't working. Currently the textview is in the top left corner.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

`android:gravity="center"` For `TextView` Only align text to center Inside `TextView`.

So, You need to add `android:gravity="center"` to LinearLayout for align TextView Inside LinearLayout.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using two linear layout inside each other... First one is horizontal and its designed to put everything to the left... User relative layout and then vertical linear layout

Answer (score 0):

try making textview width match parent

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Try this code snippnet.Hope it works for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```